# by remaining calm- a dangling participle?

Tags: dangling-participles

I am wondering whether "remaining" is a dangling participle in the following:

By **remaining** calm, a solution is usually possible.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By remaining calm* isn't a participle phrase but a preposition phrase with the gerund<sup>†</sup> phrase *remaining calm* as its object.

But the same rule applies: if the phrase/clause containing the *-ing* form does not have an explicit subject the phrase/clause has to be 'anchored' on its implicit subject in the matrix clause to which it is attached.

Here there is no eligible subject for *remaining*: *a solution* is not semantically capable of *remaining calm*.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or gerund-participle phrase/clause—folks disagree on the nomenclature, but it's not relevant to the matter at hand.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that needs to be pointed out is that the clause *does* have a subject (other than "a solution").  It's just that the subject is unspoken.

The sentence in question is *passive*.  This means that there is an unspoken "actor".  The sentence can be (awkwardly) reworded into something such as "By remaining calm a person can usually arrive at a solution."  In this case there is no valid argument that anything is "dangling".

This is not the same as some of the more egregious cases of "dangling participles" such as "By remaining calm the car that you are driving can survive a serious accident."

Comment: Eh? "A solution is possible" isn't passive: *be* is not agentive, but it is in what is (misleadingly, to be sure) called "active" voice.